# Dataflow Write to File in Order of PCollection

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a PCollection which holds KV and has only one key-value, the key has no meaning and the value holds an Iterable of KVs. The key of this inner KV is a number and the value of this KV is an Iterable of Strings.
The PCollection is defined like this:

```
PCollection<KV<String, Iterable<KV<Long, Iterable<String>>>>>
```

I want to write to a file on a single machine : sorted by the number, for each number and for each string in that number, a row in the file.

Using this PCollection I can have a ParDo that receives in it's processElement method all the numbers and their strings.
Now I can sort by number, iterate the numbers, for each number iterate the strings and output the string and number to the output collection.

However, when I write this collection to a file like this:

```
outputCollection.apply(TextIO.Write.withoutSharding().to(options.getOutputFilePath()));
```

The strings are not written sorted by the number, it seems the write is done in parallel even though it is done locally on a single machine.
Even though I inserted the "number : string" into the output collection sorted according to the number, in the file I see the numbers mixed up.

How can I control the order in which the TextIO.Write writes the records? Can I tell it to run in a single thread and use the order the elements were inserted to the PCollection?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output sorted text file from Google Cloud Dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110258/output-sorted-text-file-from-google-cloud-dataflow)

Comment: Also see here (reading, but same problem) -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027780/read-file-in-order-in-google-cloud-dataflow

Answer (score 1):

The elements in a PCollection are unordered. This is closely related to the fact that all elements in a PCollection may be processed on different machines, and ordering between machines would be difficult.

If you know that all of the data for a specific key fits on one machine, you could output a single element containing all the values, and then create a custom sink that writes that to a file.